# C++: check if vector<Class> is subset of vector<Class>

Tags: c++, vector, subset

I have the following piece of code. I have two strings (k1, k2), which I break into tokens by using the whitespace delimeter (t1, t2). Then I want to check if t1 is contained in t2.
Problem is that even with isSubset(t1, t1) I get a 0 value returned. 
I want to avoid using a `vector<string>` instead of `vector<StringRef>`, if possible.
What am I doing wrong? Output should be two 1's but I get two 0's instead.

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class StringRef
{
    private:
        char const*     begin_;
        int             size_;

    public:
        int size() const { return size_; }
        char const* begin() const { return begin_; }
        char const* end() const { return begin_ + size_; }

        std::string toString() {
             std::string value(begin_);
             return value;
        }

        StringRef( char const* const begin, int const size )
            : begin_( begin )
            , size_( size )
        {}

        bool operator<(const StringRef& s) const
        {
            return (strcmp(begin(), s.begin()) < 0);
        }
};


/************************************************
 * Checks if vector B is subset of vector A    *
 ************************************************/
bool isSubset(std::vector<StringRef> A, std::vector<StringRef> B)
{
    std::sort(A.begin(), A.end());
    std::sort(B.begin(), B.end());
    return std::includes(A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(), B.end());
}


/************************************************
 * Split string using delimeter; returns vector *
 ************************************************/
vector<StringRef> split3( string const& str, char delimiter = ' ' )
{
    vector<StringRef>   result;

    enum State { inSpace, inToken };

    State state = inSpace;
    char const*     pTokenBegin = 0;    // Init to satisfy compiler.
    for( auto it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it )
    {
        State const newState = (*it == delimiter? inSpace : inToken);
        if( newState != state )
        {
            switch( newState )
            {
            case inSpace:
                result.push_back( StringRef( pTokenBegin, &*it - pTokenBegin ) );
                break;
            case inToken:
                pTokenBegin = &*it;
            }
        }
        state = newState;
    }
    if( state == inToken )
    {
        result.push_back( StringRef( pTokenBegin, &str.back() - pTokenBegin ) );
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{

    string k1 = "9 10";
    string k2 = "9 10 2 3";
    vector<StringRef> t1 = split3(k1,' ');
    vector<StringRef> t2 = split3(k2,' ');

    cout<<isSubset(t1,t1)<<endl;
    cout<<isSubset(t2,t1)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: ------ CORRECTIONS -------

Changed `toString` to:

```
std::string toString() const {
    std::string value(begin_, size_);
    return value;
}
```

Changed `operator<` to: (thanks to @Mike Seymour)

```
bool operator<(const StringRef& s) const
{
    return (std::lexicographical_compare(begin(), end(), s.begin(), s.end()));
}
```

Finally, in `split3`, changed the if block before the return statement to:

```
if( state == inToken )
{
    result.push_back( StringRef( pTokenBegin, &str.back() + 1 - pTokenBegin ) );
}
```

Comment: I'm not going to debug the code for you, but `operator<` needs to use `<` rather than `<=` to define a strict ordering, to be usable by `sort`.

Comment: Also, `strcmp` only works on zero-terminated strings. Your pointers are to non-terminated substrings of a larger string. Try `std::lexicographical_compare(begin(), end(), s.begin(), s.end())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are issues in this code.

```
result.push_back( StringRef( pTokenBegin, &str.back() - pTokenBegin ) );
```

contains an off-by-one error, so the size of the last token is always too short.

```
return (strcmp(begin(), s.begin()) < 0);
```

and

```
std::string value(begin_);
```

rely on `\0` terminated C strings, but you are not using `\0` terminated C strings.

```
std::string toString() {
```

should be a const method.

After I resolved all of these issue, the code worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing out the contents of `t1` and `t2`, you'll see your `split3` function isn't working:

```
{9 10, 10}
{9 10 2 3, 10 2 3, 2 3, 3}
```

Also, your `StringRef::toString()` function is broken, and as Mike points out your `operator<` is broken (even after you fixed it to use `<` not `<=`).

> What am I doing wrong?

Instead of writing a complete program then staring at it wondering why the final result is wrong, try testing each piece of the program and check it actually does what you think it does.

You have several mistakes in this program, to find them all you need to check each piece in isolation and fix each problem. Trying to fix all of them at once will just be confusing because you won't be able to see which of the many errors is the cause of the unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately c++11 makes all these "view of" shenanigans unnecessary.

`std::reference_wrapper` provides a copyable reference (pointer-like object that can't be null).

All you need to do is provide an overload of whichever operators you need in the std:: namespace.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>


using ConstStringRef = std::reference_wrapper<const std::string>;

namespace std {
    bool operator<(const reference_wrapper<const string>& l, const reference_wrapper<const string>& r)
    {
        return l.get() < r.get();
    }
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    std::string a { "hello a" };
    std::string b { "hello b" };
    const std::string c { "hello c" };

    std::vector<ConstStringRef> views { c, b, a };
    cout << "initial" << endl;
    std::copy(begin(views), end(views), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // sort using lambda
    std::sort(begin(views), end(views), [](const ConstStringRef&r1, const ConstStringRef&r2 ) { return r1.get() < r2.get(); });
    cout << "sorted using lambda" << endl;
    std::copy(begin(views), end(views), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    reverse(begin(views), end(views));
    cout << "reversed" << endl;
    std::copy(begin(views), end(views), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::sort(begin(views), end(views));
    cout << "sorted using operator<" << endl;
    std::copy(begin(views), end(views), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
initial
hello c, hello b, hello a, 
sorted using lambda
hello a, hello b, hello c, 
reversed
hello c, hello b, hello a, 
sorted using operator<
hello a, hello b, hello c,
```

Comment: But `reference_wrapper` doesn't allow you to refer to part of a string, as this class does. There are [proposals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view) for such a thing in the standard library, but it's not standard yet.

Comment: there was a string_view in the std::experimental namespace for a while. However for your purposes it seems that you could just take copies of the substrings. boost::flyweight would be the solution if you intend there to be millions of strings which have a high probability of being repeated. Writing your own string_view correctly (and with unsurprising behaviour in all downstream use cases) will represent a large development effort.